# Tensorflow: Weighted sparse_softmax_cross_entropy for inbalanced classes across a single image

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a binary semantic segmentation task where the distribution of one class is very smalls across any input image, hence there are only a few pixels which are labeled. When using [sparse_softmax_cross_entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy)
the over all error is easily decreased when ignoring this class. Now, I'm looking for a way to weight the classes by a coefficient which penalizes missclassifications for the specific class higher compared to the other class.

The doc of the loss function states:

> **weights** acts as a coefficient for the loss. If a scalar is provided, then the loss is simply scaled by the given value. If **weights** is a tensor of shape [batch_size], then the loss **weights** apply to each corresponding sample.

If I understand this correctly, it says that specific sample in a batch get weighted differently compared to others. But this is actually not what I'm looking for. Does anyone know how to implement a weighted version of this loss function where the weights scale the importance of a specific class rather than samples?

Comment: First of all, are you sure you need softmax_cross_entropy, not sigmoid_cross_entropy?

Comment: You are missing the fact that there isn't (to my knowledge) a sparse version of the sigmoid_cross_entropy. Hence, I've to represent the labels as one-hot-encoding. In my case, the output consists of two channels where each represents a class. The sparse version of the softmax cross entropy computes a softmax across the dimensions so that a pixel (after argmax) is either one or zero.

Comment: What is the exact shape of your output(logits) and labels?

Comment: The shape of the logits is (?,214, 214, 2) and the shape of the labels is (?, 214, 214, 1). Where ? depends on the batch size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

The authors of the [U-Net paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) used a pre-computed weight-map to handle imbalanced classes.

The Institute for Anstronomy of ETH Zurich provided a [Tensorflow-based U-Net package](https://tf-unet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which contains a weighted version of the Softmax function (not sparse but they flatten their labels and logits first):

```
class_weights = tf.constant(np.array(class_weights, dtype=np.float32))
weight_map = tf.multiply(flat_labels, class_weights)
weight_map = tf.reduce_sum(weight_map, axis=1)
loss_map = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=flat_logits, labels=flat_labels)
weighted_loss = tf.multiply(loss_map, weight_map)    
loss = tf.reduce_mean(weighted_loss)
```